# Javascript equivalent of StringEscapeUtils.escape java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, extjs

How to unescape string escaped using `StringEscapeUtils` in front end.

Thank you

PS: I use `EXT-js3.4 & Jsp.`

Comment: [escape.js](http://www.web-geek.com/javascript/escape.js)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `StringEscapeUtils` (which method of that class btw.)? It would be much easier to escape using JSON ([frontend](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), [backend](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java))

Comment: Does json have seperate methods to escape and unescape strings.

Comment: Yes of course [Java escape](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONStringer.html), [Java unescape](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html), [JavaScript escape](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js#L59), [JavaScript unescape](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js#L34)